# PEPPER Robot: how to read in external data

Tags: pepper

We want to use external data (a measurement of power) to get our robot to take a command.
But the problem is that we don’t know how to read in this external datapoint in Choreographe and pair this to an action.

Could somebody tell us how we need to do this?

Kind regards
Lars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PEPPER (Softbank Robotics): How can I send "external" data (e.g., sensor) to Coregraphe Software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57275888/pepper-softbank-robotics-how-can-i-send-external-data-e-g-sensor-to-cor)

Answer (score 0):

Choregraphe [Python boxes](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/software/choregraphe/tutos/boxes.html) can be customized.
Depending on how your datapoint is published, you may be able to read it from the Python code.
For instance if your datapoint is an HTTP endpoint, you can use [httplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html) to read it, and react according to the result.